# Qui étaient les grands auteurs dont le style d'écriture (et des phrases) était le plus complexe ?

Tags: littérature

Quels sont les grands écrivains dont le style d'écriture, les tournures, et les phrases étaient plus compliqués ? Y a-t-il de la littérature contemporaine qui détient ces qualités ?

Par exemple, un major en français soutient que les phrases et tournures (mais certes pas les idées !) de Jean-Paul Sartre sont relativement plus faciles que ceux d'Albert Camus.

Comment: L'apparente complexité dépend non seulement des auteurs mais aussi des époques.

Answer (score 4):

**Sartre** et **Camus** sont connus pour leur style très simple qui tranche avec la complexité de leurs idées (dans les œuvres de fiction du moins, leurs essais sont assez complexes). *L'étranger*, par exemple, utilise un français extrêmement simple (même si en creusant ça devient de moins en moins simple). **Roland Barthes** appelait ça *Le degré zéro de l'écriture*.

En ce qui concerne la complexité du style et de l'écriture (et non pas des idées, si j'ai bien compris la question), le premier exemple qui me vient en tête est **Proust**. Ses phrases sont extrêmement longues et complexes (et magnifiques). Un débutant en français ne pourra jamais lire ça, alors qu'il pourra facilement lire *L'étranger*. Il y a aussi **Céline**, cité dans la réponse plus haut.

Pour les contemporains, je n'ai pas d'exemple évident. **Houellebecq** a écrit certains passages assez complexes, surtout dans ses deux premiers romans, mais la plus grande partie de ses livres reste assez simple (je parle toujours de style). Il y a *Assia Djebar* qui a un style assez difficile également (*L'amour, la fantasia*, par exemple), mais je ne classerais pas ça dans la catégorie "littérature française", mais plutôt "littérature maghrébine francophone".

Answer (score 1):

Le terme *grand écrivain* est sujet à discussion, je vais donc l'esquiver.

Dans l'époque contemporaine il y a l'auteur **Louis-Ferdinand Céline** qui me vient à l'esprit. Il m'a marqué par son style assez particulier et pas toujours évident à suivre. Donc à mon humble avis il rentre dans ce que tu peux appeler un **style d'écriture compliqué**.

Si tu trouves des extraits de *Féerie pour une autre fois* et de *Voyage au bout de la nuit* ça te donnera deux exemples assez différents de ce que Céline peut proposer.

Mais ça ne plaît pas forcément à tout le monde, la frontière entre un style original et un style imbuvable est vraiment très fine.

Comment: J'admire la diplomatie.

Answer (score 1):

Je rajoute, pour un exemple de style volontairement difficile à lire, **Claude Simon**. La phrase est longue, à vastes ramifications, avec beaucoup de participes présents, pour en quelque sorte obliger le lecteur à faire un travail de lecture.

Il a l'avantage d'être publié chez Minuit, qui s'est lancé sérieusement dans l'édition électronique, et donc disponible pour les liseuses.

Answer (score 0):

Je ne sais pas si cela réponds aussi à cette question mais on peut aussi citer des auteurs ou écrits qui possèdent certaines propriétés qui ne sont pas en soi complexe à comprendre mais plus complexe à écrire.

Je pense en particulier à :

1. ["La disparition"](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Disparition_%28roman%29) de Georges Perec, roman écrit sans la lettre E (qui est la lettre la plus fréquente en français)
2. ["La modification"](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9cit_%C3%A0_la_deuxi%C3%A8me_personne) de Michel Butor

Après, il existe sûrement d'autres écrits avec des particularités semblables (exemple sur le deuxième lien d'autres auteurs utilisant la deuxième personne).

Après comme déjà mentionné dans une autre réponse, le terme de grand auteurs est très subjectif, donc je mentionne ces deux exemples connus.

Answer (score 0):

On est mal armé pour comprendre **[Mallarmé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%A9phane_Mallarm%C3%A9)** :)